# How to see the list of all used clips in a timeline?

Tags: davinci-resolve

If i create a timeline in davinci resolve and drag some clips from bin on this timeline, then where is the list of clips used on this timeline ? the bin contains massive clips i don't want to sort it out one by one. I just want to see only used clips as a list.

In Nuke studio, every timeline has its own clip list. But i can't find it in resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit index lists all of the clips used in a timeline. It also provides ways to sort and filter the list, so you could limit the list to all clips containing a particular marker, for example.  Also if the filtering and sorting you require isn’t available, the edit index can export plain text, so that you can process its contents however you like.